# iCloud Photos: What happens when deleted from phone

Tags: icloud, photos

If I delete photos from my **All Photos**, will they be deleted from iCloud also?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable iCloud Photo Library all your devices stay in sync. So deleting/adding a picture on one device will delete/add it on all others (and the Cloud) as well.

Comment: thank you! What can I do to save photos on iCloud but delete from my iPhone to free up space?

Comment: @Jennifer Please ask a new question for this